# Searching unformatted dates

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a list of transaction data that I am providing a search input for so that the user can view specific transaction types and dates. In the raw JSON data that the ng-repeat consumes, the transaction `date` field is a unix timestamp.

For display purposes, the timestamp is passed through a custom date formatting filter that converts it to a human readable format.

```
{{item.date | formatDate}}
```

Now, in the search input, the terms entered are looking at the pre-filtered data, rather than the post-filtered data (i.e. searching for March 31 fails, but searching for the timestamp works as expected).

Other than creating a new `dateFormatted` field in the source JSON, is there any way to instruct the search filtering to look at post-filtered data? Any other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom filter for that purpose please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.data = [

    {
      id: 1,
      date: 1426628579
    }, {
      id: 2,
      date: 1425628539
    }, {
      id: 3,
      date: 1426668529
    }, {
      id: 4,
      date: 1433934000
    },

  ];



});

app.filter('transactionDay', function() {
  return function(items, search) {
    var filtered = [];

    if (search === undefined) {
      return items
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var transactionDate = new Date(items[i].date * 1000);
      search = new Date(search)
      if (transactionDate.getYear() == search.getYear() && transactionDate.getMonth() == search.getMonth() && transactionDate.getDay() == search.getDay()


      ) {
        filtered.push(items[i]);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" /> 
    <br/>
    Search for {{search}}
    <hr/>

    <h4> Filtered </h4>

    <p ng-repeat="item in data | transactionDay : search">id: {{item.id}} | date: {{item.date*1000 | date }}</p>

    <h4> Unfiltered </h4>
    <p ng-repeat="item in data">id: {{item.id}} | date: {{item.date*1000 | date }}</p>
  </div>
```